# Cosa significa "In tutti effetti"

Tags: phrases

Sono andato in banca, e quando l'impiegato parlava con me usava molto questa espressione; ad esempio: “Quando hai la carta in tutti effetti”.

Comment: Incontri gente strana, Farzad! :-)

Comment: Ahah, ma no,  era una persona molto decente, mi spiegava benissimo,  ma usava le parole più formale, più bancarie magari

Comment: Forse diceva "a tutti gli effetti"? (Al posto di "decente", è più corretto dire "rispettabile", "educato/-a", "gentile").

Comment: Grazie mille, allora cosa vuol dire a tutti gli effetti?

Comment: @Farzad64: completamente, da ogni punto di vista. Nel caso della banca, forse bisognava seguire una procedura con vari passaggi. "A tutti gli effetti" significa che tutti i passaggi sono stati fatti.

Comment: Apprendo adesso dalla rete che c'è chi usa “in tutti effetti” in luogo di “a tutti gli effetti”, ma per il niente che vale è la prima volta che lo sento, e anche a [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+tutti+effetti%2Ca+tutti+gli+effetti&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20tutti%20gli%20effetti%3B%2Cc0) non risulta.

Answer (score 2):

È una forma idiomatica. Significa "completamente" o "da tutti i punti di vista". Tuttavia a volte assume delle sfumature più astratte. 
Sfortunatamente il tuo esempio è incompleto quindi non riesco a contestualizzarlo.

Comment: Mai sentita, in che parte dell'Italia si usa?

Comment: Non saprei dirti la diffusione. Io sono del centro Italia e l'ho sentita abbastanza frequentemente.

Answer (score 1):

Nel contesto bancario per `effetto` si intendono degli strumenti finanziari in uso nel sistema bancario e
nel regolamento di rapporti di credito e debito tra banche, imprese, privati,etc. e di solito ci si riferisce a cambiali, assegni e le ricevute bancarie.

Dal sito [Treccani nella definizione di effetto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/effetto/):

> Con accezione più partic.: *valido a tutti gli effetti*, a tutti i fini,
>   per ogni applicazione; nel linguaggio forense: *per ogni effetto di ragione
>   e di legge*

Comment: Sì, ma l'espressione "in tutti effetti" in questo caso sembrerebbe ancor più sgrammaticata, probabilmente c'è bisogno di maggiore contesto per dare una risposta corretta.

Comment: Sono d'accordo...